# Wiped out OSX (Mac Air), to install Ubuntu 13.10 which doesn't boot

Tags: boot, macbook, macosx

What are my options? I tried to do a OSX recovery, but now the macbook air can't pick up my  wireless (but wireless is definitely working). At this point, I'd be happy with either Ubuntu, OSX, or any Linux distro working.

Comment: How did you go about installing Ubuntu? Did you make a boot partition?  What happens when you turn the computer on? Please provide us with more information and we'd be happy to get Ubuntu booting for you :D

Comment: The computer, when I turn on doesn't do anything; it just shows a logo of a folder with a question mark. I chose the option that said something like remove Mac OSX, and it removed 5 partitions. I made a bootable usb following instructions from here http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx

Comment: I see. Boot that USB, select "Try Ubuntu" when you have the option, and edit the contents of `fdisk -l` and a snapshot of GParted into your post. Also - if you can, join the general chatroom. Not sure if you have enough reputation to do so.

Answer (score 3):

I think the issue that you're running into has to do with UEFI. Perhaps simply waiting 30 seconds will reveal grub. In short Macbooks use this as a replacement for the traditional BIOS. Take a moment to look through the Mactel support teams [installation instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MactelSupportTeam/AppleIntelInstallation) and be sure to follow the steps.

I usually keep a small partition that still has OSX installed for firmware updates as well as checking things out if I suspect a hardware problem. I also have a base image with OSX only should I want to bring the machine in to the Mac store for repair. I highly recommend considering a dual boot system.

Once you've looked over the general install instructions take a look at your [hardware specific page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookAir6-2/Saucy). I made some assumptions about your version of hardware in this link but you can navigate the wiki should you have a difference version.

Answer (score 3):

This is due to Ubuntu installation not writing the NVRAM correctly after installation.  A simple fix is described at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro11-1/Saucy Step 5.  You need to boot into a live mode through a USB drive to do this.  Good luck.